# Symfony 4 : circular reference error

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm using Symfony 4 and for no reason, I have an error when I try to clear the cache :

```
Circular reference detected for service "routing.loader", path: "routing.loader".
```

I did nothing special (a composer update maybe) and I have no idea what the problem is.

Any suggestion ?

I tried to comment all routes in routing.yml and routing_dev.yml but no effect...

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution for my problem is to remove the vendor folder, and do composer install after that...

Don't know why but it's ok now !